# players roll 2 dice till one reaches 100

Tags: python, random

Each player roll two dice in a row on one turn. The amount of dice obtained is
added to the player's total points. The game ends when one of the players
the first has achieved at least 100 points.

```
from random import randint

dicesum2 = 0
dicesum1 = 0
while (dicesum1 < 100): 
    dice1 = [randint(1, 6) for i in range(2)]
    dicesum1 += sum(dice1)
    print('player 1',dice1,'|',dicesum1)
    dice2 = [randint(1, 6) for i in range(2)]
    dicesum2 += sum(dice2)
    print('player 2',dice2,'|',dicesum2)
```

i need it to end when one reaches 100. how do i check both?

if a player throws exactly one single, he loses the points obtained in the turn;

how do i check when one of the generated numbers is 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this and see if it helps out

```
from random import randint

def roll():
    return [randint(1, 6) for i in range(2)]

def check_for_one(rolls):
    for roll in rolls:
        # this could be simplified to "if 1 in rolls", this was just my preference
        if roll == 1:
            return True
    return False

dicesum2 = 0
dicesum1 = 0

while True:
    d1 = roll()
    dicesum1 += sum(d1)
    if check_for_one(d1):
        print(f"Player 1 rolled a 1 in batch: {d1}")
    print(f"Player 1 roll: {d1} | {dicesum1}")

    d2 = roll()
    dicesum2 += sum(d2)
    if check_for_one(d2):
        print(f"Player 2 rolled a 1 in batch: {d2}")
    print(f"Player 2 roll: {d2} | {dicesum2}")


    if dicesum1 >= 100:
        print(f"Player 1 won with: {dicesum1}")
        break
    elif dicesum2 >= 100:
        print(f"Player 2 won with: {dicesum2}")
        break
```

So in this example, we shove the roll out to a function and check_for_one which iterates the list you are making checking for ones and returning a boolean.

I changed the loop to `while True` so the loop wasn't responsible for the more complex condition which can be limiting.

For each player, it performs the roll, sums, checks and reports if a 1 is in the batch, reports the roll.

Finally it checks for the winner and breaks if one is at or over 100, reporting their win.

Comment: `def roll(): return random.choices(range(1,7),k=2)`

Comment: @PatrickArtner yeah I didn't think to change his roll heh

Comment: how can i check if the geneterate number are equal if it rolls 2,2 or 3,3?

Comment: You mean like

```
```
def check_equality(rolls):
    if rolls[0] == rolls[1]:
        # they are the same
```

? (you'd have to fix formatting)

Answer (score 1):

> I need it to end when one reaches 100. how do i check both?

Learn about what the `or` logical operator does:

```
dicesum1 < 100 or dicesum2 < 100
```

> how do i check when one of the generated numbers is 1?

Learn what the `in` operator does:

```py
if 1 in dice1:
    # Apply penalty.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `while` condition as follow :

```
while (dicesum1 < 100 and dicesum2 < 100):
```

Alternatively, you can also use `break` :

```
...
if dicesum1 >= 100:
    break
...
if dicesum2 >= 100:
    break
```